# WebSocket connection to 'wss://**** failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, pusher-js, laravel-websockets

```
app-bc5b78c1.js:9 WebSocket connection to 'wss://****.com:6001/app/key?protocol=7&client=js&version=7.6.0&flash=false' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

I'm use laravel 10 and beyondcode/laravel-websockets package
its work in localhost but dont work in hostinger Premium Web Hosting

config/broadcasting.php file

```php
'driver' => 'pusher',
'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
'options' => [
    'cluster' => 'ap2',
    'encrypted' => true,
    'host' => '****.com',
    'port' => 6001,
    'scheme' => 'https',
    'useTLS' => true
],
```

resources/js/bootstrap.js file

```js
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
window.Pusher = Pusher;

window.Echo = new Echo({

    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'key',
    cluster: "ap2",
    wsHost: '****.com',
    wsPort: 6001,
    wssPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: true,
    disableStats: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});
```

and run websocket with
`php artisan websockets:serve`

and use livewire with laravel

Note its work with pusher without this package

I tried to use the site without https and it didn't work